# sorting by value specific - ORDER BY

Tags: sql

I am trying to sort a query using ORDER BY where I need to sort 3 columns one by one. And the third column is value specific.

Eg: If i have 3 columns a,b and c
I need to use ORDER BY a, b desc, c='3' asc, c

What I want to do is first sort order is a, then b in desc order then I want the values of which has 3 to be sorted and then the remaining values which are not 3.

Comment: Which SQL product? In Standard SQL, the `ORDER BY` clause can only comprise a) column names, c) as clauses ('aliases'), c) ordinal positions. It looks like you are relying on a vendor extension to the Standard but your question only has the `sql` tag.

Comment: ...also, it is good practise to expose the sort order to the user via a column in the resultset anyhow.

Answer (score 9):

```
 ORDER BY
  a,
  b desc,
  CASE WHEN c = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  c
```

Comment: You need a comma after "END".

Comment: Actually can we do some thing like ORDER BY
  a,
  CASE WHEN b <> 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  c,
  CASE WHEN b = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

Comment: what i need is first sort a then b which has other values than 3 and then sort c and then again b which has values 3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server, try using CASE:

```
ORDER BY a, b desc, CASE c WHEN '3' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, c ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY
a,
b desc,
CASE c when 3 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: @Gendolkari, I think your intent is correct, but you have the 1 and 0 reversed.