# Use SQL to query in order except the first record

Tags: sql

I have an idea, e.g. I have a table containing name(Ann, Ben, Chris, Tom, John),
I want to query it using sql from letter a first, z last.

But I have a condition that I want to put John in the first record.

Comment: I agree with bluefeet. Also, if people don't answer your questions, answer them yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting by value specific - ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138430/sorting-by-value-specific-order-by)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
select name
from names
order by
  case when name = 'John' then 0 else 1 end,
  name
```

Comment: Is the case faster than the where + union? I would think with a decent index the where + union could be faster.

Comment: @aF, avoiding UNION's is not a goal in and of itself, esp if you can use `UNION ALL`, which prevents the costly check for duplicates.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is indeed better, but I liked the though outside the box :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  (SELECT * FROM atable WHERE username = 'John')
UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM atable WHERE username <> 'John' ORDER BY username)
```

Or more general:

```
  (SELECT * FROM atable ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT * FROM atable WHERE id NOT IN (
     SELECT id FROM atable ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 1)
   ORDER BY username)
```

If you **have** to avoid the union for some reason, this slower code will also work:

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
ORDER BY  
  CASE WHEN id IN (SELECT id FROM atable ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 1) 
  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  , username
```

In SQL-server the syntax is slightly different, the subquery is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM atable ORDER BY username DESC
```

Comment: Don't you need an outer query here to `SELECT` the results of the `UNION`?

Comment: Given the lack of an outer `order by`, the server is still allowed to mix up the rows from the two unions.

Comment: @GSerg, no it's not and it will not.

Comment: @Johan It normally will not. But it *may* as defined by the SQL standard. When you select records from a table without ordering, they are returned in the order of the clustered key, because it's cheaper, but the server still *may* return them in any other order.

Comment: @Yuck, no you don't need an outer select, you never need an other select with union, unless you want to do extra magic on the combined set.

Comment: @GSerg, SQL standard or not, **MySQL** does not do this period.

Comment: @Johan Is that documented (in which case it's somewhat weird, but still irrelevant as mysql is not mentioned in the question), or is that what you have been observing?

Comment: @GSerg, oops this is a general SQL question, anyway there is no SQL dialect that I know of that will mix up the order of a UNION ALL'ed resultset, it may be different for a plain `UNION`.

Comment: @GSerg, it's documented for MySQL, and I don't think it's wierd to keep rows in the order I asked them to be.

Comment: @Gserg, one more thing, there is no clustered key, because we are unioning resultsets, not tables big difference.

Comment: @Johan Not a big difference, really. I only mentioned the clustered key to say the server always does the cheapest thing. If under some uncommon circumstances it is cheaper to mix up the rows from two unions, the server is allowed to do so unless an outer `order by` is present. You only have a tiniest chance of seeing that in your life, that is true. It's just me, I prefer things that are *conceptually* correct over things that work 99.99999% of time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5885/discussion-between-johan-and-gserg)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

```
(SELECT Name
FROM Users
WHERE Name = 'John')
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE Name <> 'John'
ORDER BY Name)
```

Comment: Given the lack of an outer `order by`, the server is still allowed to mix up the rows from the two unions.

Comment: Change the UNION into UNION ALL, you are merging two mutually exclusive sets.

Comment: You will select user `john` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a case statement in the order by clause does not work with select distinct. I find the following more intuitive and works if you also need select distinct.Although it does return an extra column in the result set.

```
DECLARE @names TABLE
(
  Name varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @names 
SELECT 'Tom'

INSERT INTO @names 
SELECT 'John'

INSERT INTO @names 
SELECT 'Chris'

INSERT INTO @names 
SELECT 'Ann'

INSERT INTO @names 
SELECT 'Ben'

select Name, case when Name = 'John' then 1 else 0 end AS IsTopRow
from @names
order by IsTopRow DESC, Name
```

Results:

```
Name    IsTopRow
John    1
Ann     0
Ben     0
Chris   0
Tom     0
```