# Order By A Value In Another Field

Tags: sql-server

I have a job definition table with example data, shown below, that needs to be sorted in such a way that records that have a NextJobDefinitionID > 0 are kept together. The sort order for records where the NextJobDefinitionID = 0 does not matter. In the example the record with the JobName of "M1 P1" must follow "M1 Pre-Roll" and "M1 Pre-Roll" must follow "M1 Recurring Benefits". I am using SQL Server 2014.

Data:

[image]

My desired output would be:

```
M1 Recurring Benefits
M1 Pre-Roll
M1 P1
```

Comment: If you want to try to do this yourself, this should be pretty similar solution as any kind of hierarchy / tree is done using a recursive CTE.

Comment: Why `M1 P1` row is distinguished from another rows where  `NextJobDefinitionID = 0 `. I mean why it have  third place in your output example?

Comment: It would be much nicer if the sample data was provided as a *script* (populating a table variable), You may think Images more clearly express what you're doing but all you've given us is *typing practice* we didn't ask for - we can't copy & paste an image into SSMS.

Comment: @OtoShavadze I'd say because the previous row has the value for Next... as 8, and M1 P1 is the row 8.

Comment: The three jobs I mention must run one after the other with M1 P1 being the last in the sequence. M1 P1 does not have another job that must run after it. Maybe you can think of it as M1 P1 cannot run until M1 Pre-Roll has run. Have I answered the question?

Comment: Here is the SQL Statement

Comment: select JobDefinitionID, FloatingJobID, JobName, NextJobDefinitionID
from JobDefinitions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use SQL to query in order except the first record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523255/use-sql-to-query-in-order-except-the-first-record)

Comment: Do you have several of these linked chains in your data, or only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this constructs the required ordering:

```
declare @t table (ID int,NextID int)
insert into @t(ID,NextID) values
(1,0),
(2,5),
(3,6),
(4,2),
(5,0),
(6,4)

;With Parents as (
    select ID,ID as ParentID, 0 as Depth, NextID
    from @t
    where ID not in (select NextID from @t)
    union all
    select p.NextID,p.ParentID,Depth+1,t.NextID
    from Parents p
            inner join
        @t t
            on
                p.NextID = t.ID
    where p.NextID != 0
)
select * from Parents
order by ParentID,Depth
```

It works by building a CTE by using rows which may be freely ordered as the base case and then following the `NextID` values along the chain, keeping the original `ParentID` and increasing a `Depth` value, to then be able to have a simple `ORDER BY` at the end.

---

(Translating back to your original column/table/sample data left as an exercise for the reader, since as I say, I don't need the typing practice to transcribe it from an image)

Comment: I am sorry I did not post scripts for you to use. I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried your example but I am getting a maximum recursion exceeded. Here is my code. DECLARE @T TABLE (JobDefinitionID int, JobName varchar(50), NextJobDefinitionID int)
INSERT INTO @T (JobDefinitionID, JobName, NextJobDefinitionID) VALUES 
(0, '', 0),
(1, 'M1 Recurring Benefits', 7),
(2, 'M2 Recurring Benefits', 0),
(3, 'Accounts Receivable Report', 0),
(4, 'Accounts Payable Report', 0),
(6, 'IVD Mass Update', 0),
(7, 'M1 Pre-Roll', 8),
(8, 'M1 P1', 0)

Comment: ;WITH Parents AS (
 SELECT JobDefinitionID, JobDefinitionID AS ParentID, 0 AS Depth, NextJobDefinitionID, JobName 
 FROM @T
 WHERE JobDefinitionID NOT IN (SELECT NextJobDefinitionID FROM @T) 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT P.JobDefinitionID, P.ParentID, Depth + 1, T.JobDefinitionID, T.JobName
 FROM Parents P INNER JOIN @T T ON P.NextJobDefinitionID = T.JobDefinitionID
)
SELECT * FROM Parents
ORDER BY ParentID, Depth

Comment: @Dan - need a `where` clause to stop the chasing when `NextID` is 0. My sample data didn't have a row with ID 0, yours does (which does make things problematic if something wants to occur before that job - why are you using 0 as your special marker for "no next job" rather than `NULL`?)

Comment: I like to have my foreign keys reference a primary key. All my tables always have a primary key of 0. As for the where clause I'm not sure where that would go. If you would, please help me with that.

Comment: I add the where clause where you show but the error persists. I must have something else wrong.;WITH Parents AS (
 SELECT JobDefinitionID, JobDefinitionID AS ParentID, 0 AS Depth, NextJobDefinitionID, JobName 
 FROM @T
 WHERE JobDefinitionID NOT IN (SELECT NextJobDefinitionID FROM @T) 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT P.JobDefinitionID, P.ParentID, Depth + 1, T.JobDefinitionID, T.JobName
 FROM Parents P INNER JOIN @T T ON P.NextJobDefinitionID = T.JobDefinitionID
 WHERE P.NextJobDefinitionID != 0
)
SELECT * FROM Parents
ORDER BY ParentID, Depth

Comment: I'm not near a machine where I can work on this at the moment - but your habit of forcing what is ultimately a recursive FK structure on your tables is the main issue preventing this from working. Null is the *built-in* mechanism for representing that no real linkage exists and your decision to instead have a 0 row means that most common means of navigating FKs will end up having to have specific work-arounds to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
(select JobDefinitionID, FloatingJobID, JobName, NextJobDefinitionID from JobDefinitions
where NextJobDefinitionID <> 0)
UNION ALL
(select JobDefinitionID, FloatingJobID, JobName, 9223372036854775807 AS NextJobDefinitionID from JobDefinitions WHERE JobDefinitionID = (SELECT MAX(NextJobDefinitionID) FROM JobDefinitions))
order by NextJobDefinitionID
```

Comment: ... that the code does not make sense in general, produces wrong result, and contains the magic number of `1000000000`? It outputs all records with `NextJobDefinitionID <> 0`, and then one single record where `JobDefinitionID` equals `max(NextJobDefinitionID)`, replacing its `NextJobDefinitionID` with the magic number.

Comment: @GSerg - According to OP question, given data and expected output, this code makes sense. About `1000000000`, you are probably right, I changed it and I hope, this doesn't looks so magically now

Comment: The OP wants to order the records so that each previous record tells you what the next record must be using the `NextJobDefinitionID` field. The `M1 Recurring Benefits` tells you the next row must be with the ID of `7`, which is `M1 Pre-Roll`. The `M1 Pre-Roll` tells you the next record must be with the ID of `8`, which is `M1 P1`. Your code certainly does not do that, and I'm not sure how to describe what it does instead.